# How to use gsub to replace a value with another?

Tags: r, gsub

I have a column in a data frame which has salutation ,i.e. Title .

When i take summary of the column I get the summary like below:

```
DR. DR MS. Ms. MS 
--------------------
6  20  31  12  21
```

I planned to merge DR. as DR and MS. Ms. a MS.

So the code I wrote was

```
gsub("DR\\.", "DR",df$TITLE)
gsub("M[s/S]\\.","MS",df$TITLE)
```

but by this am not able to get the summary.... result of summary turns to be :

```
 Length     Class      Mode 
----------------------------
 6189     character   character
```

wherein I wanted the result of the summary to be

```
DR  MS
--------
26  64
```

How do I achieve this. Whats the error I am doing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `fixed = TRUE` and change the 'TITLE' to upper case so that we have only two categories

```
df$TITLE <- factor(toupper(sub(".", "", df$TITLE, fixed = TRUE)))
```

When we apply `sub/gsub`, the `factor` class changes to `character` and `summary` gives frequency/count for `factor` class and `Length` for `character` class columns.  So, we need to wrap it with `factor` or use `table`

```
table(df$TITLE)
summary(df$TITLE)
```

Comment: in this case ,I am getting the summary(df) as                                        Length     Class      Mode 
     6189 character character

Comment: But i want the end result                                                                              
DR  MS
--------
26  64

Comment: @Prajna  `summary` works on `factor` column,  YOu can use `table` or convert to `summary(factor(df$TITLE))` or `table(df$TITLE)`

Comment: thanks @akrun...I had converted the column to a character ...but had to change to factor again...

Comment: @Prajna Easier option is `table` which works on all of these classes